# Is there a way to get a GPS location from a USB device with Javascript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps, usb

I'm trying to get the location off of a GlobalSat G-Star IV USB GPS device to use in a webpage. I've found the Geolocation API and can get it to work on phones with built-in GPS (based off of http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_geolocation.asp), but it always returns "error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE" when I try to use it with my USB device on a desktop PC (using the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox). For some reason, it's not even pulling a location based on my IP address, but that's beside the point, since I need the highest accuracy possible for my project. I've made sure that my browser is allowing sites to access my location and there is nothing else blocking it that I can identify.

Is there any way to get the Geolocation API to work in this way or am I restricted to working with devices that have built-in GPS?

Comment: Try a few things out. Go to some web pages that are using geolocation at the moment and see if they are detecting your device. Read the manual and see what applications support it. My gut is that you won't be able to use it, because your browser won't know how to get data from it, but there may be browser plugins or some such to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Every site I've tried with a plugin to get GPS info has told me that my location couldn't be determined, so I'm guessing I'll have to simplify my approach a bit.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the platform you are on. Apparently firefox on linux uses GPSD http://catb.org/gpsd/ which in theory at least should allow you to access your USB connected GPS device.

http://www.andygup.net/?p=600 provides a nice overview of how the various browsers implement the geolocation API.